# Change img src created via appendTo

Tags: jquery

I have created a button via the appendTo function:

```
$('<span id="metroBtn" class="play_btns"><img src="pngs/metro.png"></span>').appendTo( '#cardSlots' );
```

I am trying to change the img src via the following, but it's not working:

```
$('#cardSlots').on('click', '#metroBtn', function(){
    $(this).attr('src','pngs/new_img.png');
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Wouldn't `this` be the `span` element, and not the `img` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your jquery, `$(this)` is referring to the element to which the click event is attached, which is the `#metroBtn` wrapper. You will need to target the `img` in order to change its source. You can do this with the [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$(this).find('img').attr('src','pngs/new_img.png');
```

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWAAjN)